# Django - String to Date - Date to UNIX Timestamp

Tags: python, django

I need to convert a date from a string (entered into a url) in the form of 12/09/2008-12:40:49. Obviously, I'll need a UNIX Timestamp at the end of it, but before I get that I need the Date object first.

How do I do this? I can't find any resources that show the date in that format? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need the `strptime` method. If you're on Python 2.5 or higher, this is a method on `datetime`, otherwise you have to use a combination of the `time` and `datetime` modules to achieve this.

Python 2.5 up:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S")
```

below 2.5:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import strptime
dt = datetime(*strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S")[0:6])
```

Comment: Still get an error? :S

>>>
>>> time1 = "08-05-2009-05-10-54"
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(time1, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/_strptime.py", line 331, in strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=08-05-2009-05-10-54  fmt=%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S
>>>

Comment: Actually, that was my fault! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`time.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) method to parse a date string. This will return a `time_struct` that you can pass to [`time.mktime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.mktime) (when the string represents a local time) or [`calendar.timegm()`](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) (when the string is a UTC time) to get the number of seconds since the epoch.